# Stuck in matrix manipulation and rearrangement

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

We have that
$A$ is a symmetric matrix $n\times n$, $b$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, $C$ is a scalar, and $d$ is a $n\times 1$ vector.

The expression

$\left(Ad\right)'A^{-1}\left(Ad\right)-2b'A^{-1}Ad+C$

can be rewritten as

$\left(Ad-b\right)'A^{-1}\left(Ad-b\right)+C-b'A^{-1}b$

I really don't get where $b'A^{-1}b$ comes from. Any help?

Edited: Corrected B with b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first term of the rewritten expression is:

$$\left(Ad-b\right)'A^{-1}\left(Ad-b\right)= (Ad)'A^{-1}(Ad) - 2b'A^{-1}Ad + b'A^{-1}b$$

and since $b'A^{-1}b$ is not in your original expression, you need to remove it.

Comment: You are right, I used by mistake B but is b, n by 1. Thank you very much.